# mongo atlas free sandbox in production

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am going to deploy client's webapp using mongoose (mongo atlas) and gotta admit, he is not very generous, i know that Sanbox (M0 cluster) is not suitable for production mode but wanted to know why? are there any reason that it is not secure to use M0 in production, i mean it's storage is suitable for website needs Thanks in advance, it is really simple application, with add post delete post and edit post like simple wordpress theme. thanks in advance.

P.S: i could not find any real problem in this [link](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/free-shared-limitations/)

Comment: No logging, and no auditing would make that a bear to troubleshoot.  100 ops/sec is rather small for a website.

Comment: I was planning to get M2 cluster but it has 200ops per second and it is only double so it does not matters. by the way if what would happen if 101 user went to website at the same time

Comment: the 101st connection would be refused, which would likely return an error or raise an exception in the driver.

Comment: so if website has more than 100 visitor at the same time it would crash?

Comment: M0 Free Tier and M2/M5 shared clusters are allowed a maximum of 500 connections.
 
WHAT? only 500 visitor can visit the website at the same time? are you sure

Comment: not website visitors, connections to the database - not necessarily the same thing.  It would be pretty rare for a website visitor to require a persistent connection for the duration of their visit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209017/discussion-between-ilia-and-joe).

Comment: For production deployments, predictable resources and support are usually strongly desirable. If this isn't a mission critical site for your client (i.e. they are OK with unpredictable performance and no support agreement/SLA) and free tier limitations aren't a problem, this might work out. It sounds like your application is a basic CMS, so depending on your use case I imagine most of the scaling requirements would be around viewing content rather than editing. You can scale views very efficiently by caching output instead of having every page view fetch unchanging data from the database.

Comment: unfortunately it is too late to add redis to the code